# Ettus UHD Python API on Windows binaries

Tags: python, windows, uhd

I am trying to use the UHD python API for an Ettus SDR on Windows.

I was told that I could use the Windows pre-built binaries, but I'm not sure they support UHD Python API.  I copied the `uhd.dll` into `site packages\uhd` and was able to import UHD, but at that point, UHD is empty. It has no attributes (ie `usrp`).

Is it possible to use the UHD python API with the pre-built Windows binaries?

I tried building the source. Cmake generates fine, but solution fails with error 1. I'm still trying to figure out my issues there.